How to override animation logic in SwiftUI
I'm confused about how animations work in SwiftUI. Functionally, I know wrapping a change inside withAnimation block will cause the change to be animated but exactly how that's achieved underneath is a complete blackbox.
More specifically, I'm attempting to animate the change in position of a map annotation. Wrapping the same change in withAnimation using Apple's MapKit causes the annotation to move from the previous position to the new position. However, doing the same in Mapbox causes the previous annotation to disappear and then reappear at the new location.
Here's the MRE using MapKit:
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    static let londonA = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 51.507222,
        longitude: -0.1275
    )
    
    static let londonB = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 51.508222,
        longitude: -0.1276
    )
}

struct MapkitMapView: View {
    private let position = MapCameraPosition.region(
        MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: .londonA,
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005)
        )
    )
    @State var curLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = .londonA
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(initialPosition: position) {
            Annotation("id", coordinate: curLocation) {
                Circle()
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            Button("Change location") {
                withAnimation {
                    curLocation = .londonB // SAME CHANGE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And here's the same thing using Mapbox (to use the Mapbox SDK, you'll need to create a Mapbox account):
import SwiftUI
@_spi(Experimental) import MapboxMaps

struct MapboxMapView: View {
    private let position = Viewport.camera(
        center: .londonA,
        zoom: 16
    )
    @State var curLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = .londonA

    var body: some View {
        Map(initialViewport: position) {
            MapViewAnnotation(coordinate: curLocation) {
                Circle()
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .overlay(alignment: . bottomTrailing) {
            Button("Change location") {
                withAnimation {
                    curLocation = .londonB // SAME CHANGE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

You might say "of course, because they're two different libraries," but I'm trying to understand what causes them to behave differently. Maybe the different is incomprehensible and tucked away deep inside their source code somewhere, but where? I've search everywhere inside the source code (specifically Mapbox) and don't see anything related to how to animate the positional change.
If there's anything, I want to override it so that Mapbox behaves like MapKit.

More generally, if I define two custom Views and wrap the same state change with withAnimation, without using the parameters of withAnimation, what causes them to animate differently?

EDIT: MRE from suggestion in comment:
import SwiftUI
@_spi(Experimental) import MapboxMaps

struct AnimatedMap: View, Animatable {
    private let position = Viewport.camera(
        center: .londonA,
        zoom: 16
    )
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    
    var animatableData: AnimatablePair<Double, Double> {
        get { AnimatablePair(x, y) }
        set {
            x = newValue.first
            y = newValue.second
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(initialViewport: position) {
            MapViewAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: x, longitude: y)) {
                Circle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnimatedMapView: View {
    @State var x = 51.507222
    @State var y = -0.1275
    @State var i = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        AnimatedMap(x: x, y: y)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .animation(.smooth(duration: 5), value: x)
            .animation(.smooth(duration: 5), value: y)
            .overlay(alignment: . bottomTrailing) {
                Button("Change location") {
// ###### Doing things quickly causes issues
                    let (x_i, y_i) = [(51.508222, -0.1276), (51.507222, -0.1275)][i % 2]
                    x = x_i
                    y = y_i
                    i += 1
                }
            }
    }
}


I don't want to give MapBox my credit card info so I can't test it out myself, but you should be able to create a Animatable wrapper that wraps a Map. See here for an example where I added animation to something that doesn't native support animations. Also in this post I demonstrated that adding a custom conformance to Animatable creates a different animation from the one SwiftUI automatically infers.

That said, MapKit.Map doesn't actually conform to Animatable, so that its animation might be created by something internal to SwiftUI. But in any case, Animatable is for customising what you want to animate. There is CustomAnimation, which allows you to define your own animation curves (how things animate).

Does doing that cause the entire wrapped view to be re-drawn on every frame when animating? I'm worried about performance here since the Map is heavy

I was looking into manually animating using CADisplayLink but now I'm conflicted. Would you recommend using Animatable over CADisplayLink? I read that CADisplayLink is synchronized with the refresh rate and hence smoother?

Instead of worrying about performance. Please actually try it and measure the performance. Sometimes results can be surprising. If you are using SwiftUI I would definitely prefer Animatable over CADisplayLink. If you want to use CADisplayLink, I'd suggest making a UIViewRepresentable wrapping MapBox's UIKit view instead.

I'm hesitant to use Animatable because it seems to behave incorrectly when I interrupt the previous animation with a new one. Namely, the animated point gets stuck in between the two destination points. I edited the post to show this with an MRE.

Do you think there's something wrong with the suggested use of CADisplayLink here? Besides the issue with CADisplayLink not being thread safe that is.

And regarding the performance. I surely will but I can physically see that the animation is sometimes choppy and laggy. Perhaps it's due to what you suggested in the comments here
